# T4 indent code included from another file

Tags: c#, formatting, t4

Assume you have a template, in which you want to include code from another file. Say the template is named `Template.tt` and has the following content:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="App" #>

namespace <#= Namespace #>
{
    public partial class <#= ClassName #>
    {
<#@ include file="Snippet.txt" #>
    }
}
```

The `Snippet.txt` contains code for the body of the class, with a trailing new line character:

```
public void Function() 
{
}
```

However, if you tried to run the template, you'd get code that looks something like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class MyClass
    {
public void Function() 
{
}
    }
}
```

One way to indent it is by indenting every line from the included file by the amount needed. However, this is not a satisfactory solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use function `PushIndent()` and `PopIndent()` in your template like this:

```
namespace <#= Namespace #>
{
    public partial class <#= ClassName #>
    { <# PushIndent("        "); #>

<#@ include file="Snippet.txt" #>
<# PopIndent(); #>

    }
}
```

Except this is not going to work, because the generated printer code uses the function `Write()` to print the output, however, `Write()` disregards indents...

But! You can actually control what function implementation your template ends up calling for printing the output. When T4 generates a printer class for your code, it automatically creates a base class with functions like `Write()`, `WriteLine()`, `TransformText()` etc. Then, the generated template is set to inherit from that class, overriding `TransformText()` to print their own text.

The idea is to provide your own base class, which complies with duck interface of that base class, in order to make `Write()` use indents. T4 allows you to do that! See for example [this blogpost for starters](https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/t4-runtime-templates-base-class/).

To use indents, notice that they are needed only for new lines. Then, change `Write()` to the following:

```cs
public void Write(string textToAppend) 
{
     GenerationEnvironment.Append(textToAppend.Replace("\r\n", "\r\n" + currentIndent));
}
```

And inherit from your base class in the template (say, the base classes' name is `CodePrinterBase`):

```cs
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" inherits="CodePrinterBase" #>
<#@ assembly name="App" #>

namespace <#= Namespace #>
{
    public partial class <#= ClassName #>
    { <# PushIndent("        "); #>

<#@ include file="Snippet.txt" #>
<# PopIndent(); #>

    }
}
```

Result:

```cs
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class MyClass
    {
        public void Function() 
        {
        }

    }
}
```

If you want to also eliminate the new line after the snippet, remove the trailing new line in that snippet.

To be clear, `PushIndent()` is after the bracket like that because a new line needs to be inserted *after* that code has run. If you put it below the bracket and leave a blank line after it, like below, you'd get an extra empty line in the output:

```
{ 
<# PushIndent("        "); #>

<#@ include file="Snippet.txt" #>
```

Running that would give you:

```cs
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class MyClass
    {

        public void Function() 
        {
        }

    }
}
```

This worked flawlessly for me!